# SAS - Creating a week variable

Tags: date, sas

*I'm using SAS 9.3*

I need to create a way to sum up by week total, and I have no idea how to do it. So basically I have a year list of dates (left column below) with a total from that date (the right column). Our week goes from Friday to the previous Thursday (e.g. Thursday Oct 17 through Friday the Oct 25th).

An issue I also have is as you see the dates on the left are not completely daily and don't always have a Thursday date before the last Friday date. Would any know a way to add these weeks up - Week 1, Week 2, etc etc ...?

Thanks for any help that can be provided

```
2013-01-01  3

2013-01-02  8

2013-01-03  8

2013-01-04  10

2013-01-06  1

2013-01-07  10

2013-01-08  14

2013-01-09  12

2013-01-10  8

2013-01-11  9

2013-01-12  1

2013-01-14  12

2013-01-15  8

2013-01-16  5

2013-01-17  15

2013-01-18  7

2013-01-20  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivial way:

```
data want;
set have;
weekno = ceil((date-'03JAN2013'd)/7);
run;
```

IE, subtract the first thursday and divide by 7, (so 1/1-1/3 is weekno=0).

`INTCK` function is also adept at calculating this.  The basic structure is

```
weekno=intck('WEEK.5','04JAN2013'd,date); *the second argument is when you want your first week to start;
```

WEEK means calculate weeks, # on left side of decimal is multiple week groups (2 week periods is WEEK2.), on right side is shift index (from the default sunday-saturday week).

You could also create a format that contained your weeks, and use that.

Comment: Thank you for your response -- The third part of the intck "date" - is this referring to my actual date column (which is currently called Activity_date__C)?  
    `data true_start_5;`  
 `set true_start_4;`
 
 `WEEK_date=intck('WEEK.5','04JAN2013'd,activity_date__C);`

 
    `run;`

Comment: Yes.  INTCK compares two values (args 2 and 3) and says how many boundaries of (arg 1) type are crossed.